# Project Structure with composer

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to create a project with composer-file.
Reason is primarily a dependency which I never want to upload to git.
My intended structure is this:

> project-root-folder
>   - project-sub-folder(s)
>   - vendor  (with `require`d dependencies)
>   - index.php
>   - composer.json
>   - README.md

But the installed structure using composer is this:

> project-root-folder
>   - vendor
>   - vendor/composer
>   - vendor/smarty (dependency)
>   - vendor/my-project
>   - composer.json

I know that there are special installers for many different projects, I just don't understand that an installer is required to get the intended structure and also not how to do it without a special installer.

This is the content of one composer file I tried:

```
{   
    "name": "wdb/tutorial-oop",  
    "require": {  
        "smarty/smarty": "~3.1"  
    }
}
```

When I tried this composer-json content in a local file and just extecute `composer install` I get the same structure:

```
{  
    "require": {  
        "wdb/tutorial-oop": "dev-master"  
    }
}
```

So my question is, how a composer file has to look that the project structure is created like I described in the top of this question. **The basic problem is that I don't want my project being installed as dependency in the vendor-directory but in the root of the project folder, and additionally that I don't want to use the composer autoloader.**

Edit:
On request here my full composer file inside the project root:

```
{
    "name": "wdb/tutorial-oop",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Your package description goes here",
    "keywords": ["oop","mvc","tutorial"],
    "homepage": "https://barlians.com",
    "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "David Bruchmann",
            "email": "david.bruchmann@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "https://barlians.com",
            "role": "Author, Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "david.bruchmann@gmail.com"
    },
    "require": {
        "smarty/smarty": "~3.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not add your project to `require` section. You already have it, you don't need to install it again.

Comment: @rob006 I did it only in the last local composer file and executed with "composer install". That's the same I think like on commandline `composer require my/project`

Comment: composer just handles and touches the vendor folder. and directly a tip: if you are new to composer, do not write composer.json manually. and have a look in vendor/composer - it will be the autoloaders

Comment: @NormanM thanks, what you propose how to create the composer file?

Comment: @NormanM concerning autoloader I know composer is offering that. I just wrote an own one especially for this project.

Comment: @NormanM you might know enough to earn the bounty I set.

Comment: You should share full content of your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @rob006 done, Thanks for having a look ;-)

Comment: Did you pasted it twice in the question, or your `composer.json` actually looks like that?

Comment: @rob006 the long composer-file-content is inside the repository on github. The short one with `{  
    "require": {  
        "wdb/tutorial-oop": "dev-master"  
    }
}  ` is only locally to install the project. The one with `{   
    "name": "wdb/tutorial-oop",  
    "require": {  
        "smarty/smarty": "~3.1"  
    }
}  ` was to test installing locally. If something concerning these files might be wrong you can consider that in the answer.

Comment: So how you're trying to install your project? `composer require wdb/tutorial-oop` in empty directory?

Comment: yes right. `composer require wdb/tutorial-oop` in empty directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're installing your project in incorrect way. The `composer require` command is for installing dependencies, so they're installed to the `vendor` directory.

For installing a project you should use the [`create-project`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) command:

```
composer create-project wdb/tutorial-oop
```

Comment: You saved an event today for me, so you deserve the bounty, no matter what ;-)

Comment: that will pull the project from Packagist, right? Can you do a `create-project` command to load from github or bitbucket or wherever?

Comment: @Jakar You can use `--repository` switch for that. But cloning repository directly from source may be a better option.